# Datatables- Getting the total when there are null values

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables to calculate the all of the rows in the column and display the total in the footer of the table.

Here's the problem: It appears that whenever there is a null value in any of the rows of the column that I'm calculating, the total gets displayed as NaN.

How can I get DataTables to ignore the null values in the column and just total up the non-null values?

```
<div align="center">
     <table id = 'mytabl' class="display compact nowrap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for num in numberdata.mytable_set.all %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ num.col1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ num.col2 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
         <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
         </tfoot>
    </table>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#mytabl').DataTable({
                "searching": true,
                "pageLength": 40,
                "scrollX": true,
                "paging": false,
                "info": false,
                drawCallback: () => {
                  const table = $('#mytabl').DataTable();
                  const tableData = table.rows({
                    search: 'applied'
                  }).data().toArray();
                  const totals = tableData.reduce((total, rowData) => {
                    total[0] += parseFloat(rowData[1]);
                    total[1] += parseFloat(rowData[2]);
                    return total;
                  }, [0, 0]);
                  $(table.column(1).footer()).text(totals[0]);
                  $(table.column(2).footer()).text(totals[1]);
                }
              })
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: try changing from **rowData[1]** to **+rowData[1]**......

Comment: This is probably the best/easiest way to do it ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const totals = tableData.reduce((total, rowData) => {
                total[0] += rowData[1] ? parseFloat(rowData[1]) : 0;
                total[1] += rowData[2] ? parseFloat(rowData[2]) : 0;
                return total;
              }
```

How bout this if the value is null add zero

Comment: That works pretty well. And is there a way to hide the total from being displayed if all rows in the column are null?